# Twitter API: how to get if User B is following authenticated User A in `statuses/mentions_timeline` call

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm making a call to get my timeline mentions for any `User A` on my platform. I want to only care about `User(s) B` that are following `User A`.

Upon looking at the mentions payload returned, there is a `user` object in there. However, it only has a `following` field, denoting if `User A` is following `User B`, but there is no `friends` field to inform me if `User B` is following `User A`

Am I not seeing a field I can use here? Is it possible to find this out without making another call?

Here is the user object from the mentions call:

```
 {
   id,
   id_str,
   name,
   screen_name,
   location,
   description,sometimes we make up facts about animals lol #fakenews',
   url,
   entities,
   {
     description,
   },
   protected,
   followers_count,
   friends_count,
   listed_count,
   created_at,
   favourites_count,
   utc_offset,
   time_zone,
   geo_enabled,
   verified,
   statuses_count,
   lang,
   contributors_enabled,
   is_translator,
   is_translation_enabled,
   profile_background_color,
   profile_background_image_url,
   profile_background_image_url_https,
   profile_background_tile,
   profile_image_url,
   profile_image_url_https,
   profile_link_color,
   profile_sidebar_border_color,
   profile_sidebar_fill_color,
   profile_text_color,
   profile_use_background_image,
   has_extended_profile,
   default_profile,
   default_profile_image,
   following,
   follow_request_sent,
   notifications,
   translator_type,
 }
```

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use the call to get followers? https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-followers-list

Comment: I don't mind, but I would have to control the rate limit for another type of API call. Figured I'd try to simplify the design before doing that.